# Erro entre directive e controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, diretivas-de-compilação

Arquivos:
        index.html
        controllers/controle.js
       directives/diretiva.js
      directives/botao.html

*eu tenho uma função chamada $scope.mudar(idade) = function(){....}; no controle.js
*na diretiva tenho templateUrl: "botao.html" e scope{funcao: "&"};
*no index tenho <\botao funcao="mudar(idade)"></botao>
*no botao.html tenho <\button ng-click="funcao(20)"> Teste </button>

quero chamar a função mudar de dentro da diretiva mas fica dando o seguinte erro 
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'mudar' in 1

Answer (score 0):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
angular.module('').directive('SuaDiretiva', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'botao.html',
        scope: {
            idade: '=',
        },
        controller: _SeuController
    }
});

var _SeuController = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

    $scope.mudar = function (idade) {
       //Sua funcao usando idade, ou scope.idade
    };
}];
```

Explicando sobre o citado acima: Voce tem sua diretiva e voce pode passar como parametro a idade, sendo restrita como atributo. Já o seu controller logo abaixo referenciado na diretiva.

Como você está usando arquivos separados para seu controller, basta apenas colocar como você definiu o mesmo.